# Find and mark items with given composition in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a couple of million rows of data is given below.

```
CUSTOMER_NO     SERVICE
11111111        AB
11111111        BC
11111111        XY
11111111        SA
55555555        AB
55555555        BC
55555555        SA
55555555        HG
77777777        WE
77777777        LK
77777777        AS
77777777        GG
22222222        AB
22222222        BC
22222222        SA
99999999        WE
99999999        AS
99999999        GG
```

We have decided to mark our customers with who are enjoying a few of our services as Gold Group or Silver Group.

I need to summarise them in below manner.

```
CUSTOMER_NO SERVICE     **MARKER**
11111111    AB      SILVER +XY
11111111    BC      SILVER +XY
11111111    XY      SILVER +XY
11111111    SA      SILVER +XY
55555555    AB      SILVER +HG
55555555    BC      SILVER +HG
55555555    SA      SILVER +HG
55555555    HG      SILVER +HG
77777777    WE      GOLD + LK
77777777    LK      GOLD + LK
77777777    AS      GOLD + LK
77777777    GG      GOLD + LK
22222222    AB      SILVER
22222222    BC      SILVER
22222222    SA      SILVER
99999999    WE      GOLD
99999999    AS      GOLD
99999999    GG      GOLD
```

The composition of Silver, Gold etc is as below.

```
GOLD    WE
GOLD    AS
GOLD    GG
SILVER  AB
SILVER  BC
SILVER  SA
```

Due to the sheer size of it, it is difficult for me to do it in Excel, Also being a newbie to Power Bi I'm struggling with the mesh up.

Can you please help me to pull this off in Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code (Data - the first table from your post, Markers - the last). Note, if, for instance, Service = XY appears before others, then for Customer = 11111111 Marker fills as **XY + SILVER**, not SILVER + XY.

```
let
    group = Table.Group(Data, {"CUSTOMER_NO"}, {"MARKER", each _[SERVICE]}),
    transform = Table.TransformColumns(group, {"MARKER", each Text.Combine(
                List.Distinct(List.Transform(_, each try Markers{[SERVICE = _]}[MARKER] otherwise _)),
                " + ")}),
    join = Table.Join(Data,{"CUSTOMER_NO"},transform,{"CUSTOMER_NO"})
in
    join
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I'm getting Error.

Expression.Error: The import Data matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

Comment: Just replace Data in my code for Name of your data table, and Markers - for Name of your dimension table (last table in your post).

Comment: It is giving results like AB + BC+XY+Silver

Comment: It's because you have another table/column names in your dimension table. Replace table/column names in following piece of code for yours:
Markers{[SERVICE = _]}[MARKER]

Answer (score 0):

Load both tables into power BI, and use the relationship icon to join the customer table service fields and the reference table. This will allow a table to be built giving you all three rows

Comment: This does is not a full answer. How do you acount if a customer has ALL the option that compose silver or gold status?

Comment: Tried doing that but as mxix said, it is not possible to derive the grouping using it.